# Cloudera Manager Failed to authenticate : Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, cloudera-manager

I am currently trying to learn how can I install and configure Cloudera before using it.

So I install in VirtualBox, Ubuntu 14.04, Cloudera Manager. I would like to try it on a pseudo single node (only my computer: no cluster).

I manage to finish the installation. Then to Specify hosts for your CDH cluster installation ; localhost 127.0.0.1

My problem is on the "Provide SSH login credentials." step

Root access to your hosts is required to install the Cloudera packages. This installer will connect to your hosts via SSH and log in either directly as root or as another user with password-less sudo/pbrun privileges to become root. 
Login To All Hosts As:  Root

You may connect via password or public-key authentication for the user selected above. Authentication Method: All hosts accept same password
Enter Password:*********
SSH Port: 22

Then Continue button lead to this

Installation failed on all hosts.
 Installation failed. Failed to authenticate.

"Exhausted available authentication methods"

I tried to reset the root password, didn't change..
I tried to use an other user who had permissions passwordless (not sure i did it right.. but didn't work)
I tried to use public key ssh following tutorials with this

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But i can't browse the path of id_rsa.pub... because Cloudera Manager doesn't have the permission to acess /.ssh/ :(

I assume I didn't fully understood what is behind this step but there is no tutorial to pass it. 
Any solution to configure this ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This worked for us as well using Cloudera Manager 5.3.4.

Comment: I am running clusterdock(container) on AWS instance for running multi-node CDH cluster. but getting the same error. I have provided pem file still getting same error  "Exhausted available authentication methods"

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue and after a lot of research in the internet I managed to fix the problem. Follow the below steps to fix it.

> sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

In the file now look for **PermitRootLogin without-password** and replace it with this

> PermitRootLogin yes

Now restart the ssh service

> sudo service ssh restart

retry the installation and it should work. Comment if it has worked and spread the news.

Comment: I am running clusterdock(container) on AWS instance for running multi-node CDH cluster. but getting the same error. I have provided pem file still getting same error "Exhausted available authentication methods"

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-94:/home/ubuntu# ssh localhost -i ~/.ssh/SparkRecommendation.pem
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".

Connection to localhost closed.

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-94:/home/ubuntu# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep PermitRootLogin
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin yes
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered such problem when I configured my localhost. After while, I figured out:

1. Add rsa private key located at ./ssh/id_rsa to cloudera manager instead of your public key. In popup, if you don't see the hidden folder, right click your mouse to show hidden folder.
2. Enter your root password as passphrase

make sure you enable root login and login as root, https://askubuntu.com/questions/451950/how-to-configure-lightdm-to-allow-manual-logins-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: you might also need to  cat id_rsa.pub > authorized_keys

Answer (score 2):

Let's consolidate everything in one post:

Default, Root user is locked in ubuntu/Linux.To unlock, first need to reset password. It asks for Password twice.

```
$ sudo passwd root
 Enter UNIX password:
 Retype UNIX password:
```

Unlock root user

```
$ sudo passwd -u root
```

Open /etc/ssh/sshd_config in an editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

In the file now look for PermitRootLogin without-password and replace it with this

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Restart SSH service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow below mentioned three step its working for me

Open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in an editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find and update the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Restart the ssh service.

```
sudo service restart ssh
```

Thanks for valuable post