# Cloudera Manager [Exhausted available authentication methods ]

Tags: cloudera-manager

I'm trying to install Cloudera Manager on a single node and I faced this problem, it's shown in the details that an [Exhausted available authentication methods]

[image: image here]

Could you help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloudera Manager Failed to authenticate : Exhausted available authentication methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428242/cloudera-manager-failed-to-authenticate-exhausted-available-authentication-met)